# how to filter out elements in a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, error-handling

I have a list of links linking to json files. Some of them are blank or carry some errors and fail when I tried to load them as

```
data = urllib2.urlopen(www.whatever.co.uk).read()
data = json.loads(data)
```

what I need is to create a list of "good" links. I was thinking of creating a for loop as:

```
links = []
for i in urls:
    try:
        data = urllib2.urlopen(str(i)).read()
        data = json.loads(data)
        links.append(url)
    except:
    raise
```

but I get this error

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I know for sure that many links are good since I tried them individually. How can I exclude those faulty links? Thanks

Comment: replace `raise` with `pass`

Comment: You are already adding only good links in to the `links` .Show sample of urls and should it be `links.append(str(i))`

Comment: You should probably `decode` your data, I think some contain non-ascii characters. `data.decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are raising the inner exception. If you want to ignore it replace raise with pass. Like so:

```
links = []
for i in urls:
    try:
        data = urllib2.urlopen(str(i)).read()
        data = json.loads(data)
        links.append(url)
    except:
        pass
```

For larger applications this is a bit bad practice because you don't see what errors you encounter. Consider logging the error and continuing, or counting the errors and generating a single exception at the end if you have too many errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you call raise, then your script will raise an error and stop execution.

I prefer [`try-except-else`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) in such conditions, it looks more readable to me

```
good_links = []
bad_links = []
for i in urls:
    try:
        data = urllib2.urlopen(str(i)).read()
        data = json.loads(data)
    except Exception:
        bad_links.append(url)  # corrupted url or json data.
    else:
        good_links.append(url)
```

Above example place the bad links to a separate list, but if you do not need that, you can simply use `pass` instead of `bad_links.append(url)`

Comment: Also, be more specific in the `except` clause. Usually you want to catch `Exception` at most. For example currently this code prevents you killing the program with a SIGINT (Ctrl-C) because it catches the resulting `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Comment: Right, but since this is a dimple example for what the OP had asked for, I try to write a basic `try-except-else`. Beyond simplicity, exception handling have many options.

Answer (score 0):

the correct form is:

```
links = []
for i in urls:
    try:
        data = urllib2.urlopen(str(i)).read()
        data = json.loads(data)
        links.append(url)
     except:
     pass
```